# Filtering R data.frame based on multiple constraints

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, min, overlap

So i am still fairly new at R, and i have been looking around about how to filter a dataframe based on multiple constraints and calculations such that it returns a new dataframe. I was looking around and i know how to filter using `%in%`, and i have used that many times, but i am looking for some advice on filtering a dataset beyond one or two constraints where that syntax can be used.

I have a dataframe with 78,812 rows. In column `PeakName` i have identifiers pointing to a "peak" in my data. There are only 13,000 peaks, so each peak often shows up a handful of times in the dataframe. For each unique `PeakName` there are multiple `motifs` with different PValue scores associated with them. Each motif also has a `start` and a `stop` location.

My goal is to create a new dataframe where:

1. for each `PeakName` i find the `motif` with the lowest `PValue` and add it to the new dataframe
2. using the `start` and `stop` locations for the motifs, i discover if there are any motifs that overlap the one that was just added to the new dataframe. If there are, i remove those as possibilities to add to the new dataframe.
3. if there are any remaining `motifs` for this `PeakName`, i return to step 1, and repeat this process until there are no more possible `motifs` left.
4. NOTE: if there are two peaks with equal `PValue` where this value is currently the lowest value, i would pick the "Primary" motif one instead of the "Secondary" motif one.

Example (simplified) Data:

```
Motif      Start   Stop    PValue     PeakName
Primary    4       10      5          Peak1
Primary    5       11      4          Peak1
Secondary  12      18      8          Peak1
Secondary  8       16      6          Peak1
Primary    12      18      9          Peak1
Secondary  3       9       7          Peak2
Primary    5       11      7          Peak2
```

Desired output of above Data:

```
Motif      Start   Stop    PValue     PeakName
Primary    5       11      4          Peak1
Secondary  12      18      8          Peak1
Primary    5       11      7          Peak2
```

Any advice would be much appreciated, as i have been baffled on how to write something to do this, and it is a task i believe should be fairly simple, but keeps eluding me. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you have explained the rules in your head that allowed you to produced that output. Are we supposed to put some different weight on primary and secondary motifs? Why does `Secondary  3       9       7          Peak2` not qualify for inclusion? Why was second row in the first overlap (rows 1 and 2) chosen but the first row of the second overlap (rows 3 and 4) chosen. Programming requires a lot more than understanding the syntax. Most critically it requires a clear, unambiguous problem description.

Comment: `Secondary 3 9 7 Peak2` does not qualify for inclusion as per rule `(4)`, because it has the same PValue as the Primary motif in Peak2, but when that is the case i would place priority on Primary instead of Secondary. The second row was chosen because of all the Peak1 PValues, it has the lowest. The row is first chosen by the minimum PValue present, which is in the second row. This overlaps with the first, fourth, and fifth row, which is why these rows were not included in the final output. Sorry, i thought my explanation was more clear than it seems to be

Answer (score 0):

You may want to clean up a bit to catch edge cases such as ties. Note the use of a 'helper' column to deal with Primary/Secondary motif selection:

```
df2 <- {}
for (peak in unique(df$PeakName)) {
    tmp <- subset(df, PeakName==peak)
    tmp$helper <- tmp$Pvalue + ifelse(tmp$Motif=="S", 0.1, 0)

    while (nrow(tmp) > 0) {
        ind <- which.min(tmp$helper)
        df2 <- rbind(df2, tmp[ind,])
        remove <- (tmp$Start >= tmp$Start[ind] & tmp$Start <= tmp$Stop[ind]) | (tmp$Stop >= tmp$Start[ind] & tmp$Stop <= tmp$Stop[ind])
        tmp <- tmp[!remove,]
    }
}
```

Comment: any suggestions on how to alter the 'helper' column when dealing with motif selection if i have 6 different motifs instead of two? In one of my files i have: "Tbr_prim_8bp", "Tbr_prim_12bp", "Tbr_sec_8bp", "Tbr_sec_12bp", "Smad3_prim", "Smad3_sec", and that is the order in which i would hope to prioritize them in that condition.

Comment: Add 0.1, 0.2, ..., 0.6 in the appropriate order

Comment: I guess i am a bit confused on how the ifelse statement would work? Are you implying that i would need a unique identifier for each of my motifs, accompanied by 0.1, 0.2, etc in the order that i would like to rank the motifs? So i would need `tmp$helper <- tmp$Pvalue + ifelse(tmp$Motif=="Tbr_prim_8bp", 0.1, 0)`  as well as `tmp$helper <- tmp$Pvalue + ifelse(tmp$Motif=="Tbr_prim_12bp", 0.2, 0)` etc?

Comment: You can use a vector instead: `motif_lookup <- seq(0.1,0.6,0.1); names(motif_lookup) <- c("Tbr_prim_8bp", "Tbr_prim_12bp", ...); tmp$helper <- tmp$Pvalue + motif_lookup[tmp$Motif]`